# How to create a multi dimensional array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do you create a multi dimensional array in Javascript using a for loop ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 13):

```
var test = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    test.push([i, "lol"]);
}
```

Comment: Simple and works fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
var sDataArray = MultiDimensionalArray(2, 2);

function MultiDimensionalArray(iRows, iCols) {
    var i;
    var j;
    var table = new Array(iRows);

    for (i = 0; i < iRows; i++) {

        table[i] = new Array(iCols);

        for (j = 0; j < iCols; j++) {
            table[i][j] = "";
        }
    }
    return (table);
}
```

Comment: It looks like this function won't work when initializing arrays with more than 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0;i<100;++i){
  arr[i] = [];
  for(var j = 0; j < 100; ++j){
    arr[i][j] = i*j;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an array of arrays.

```
var arr = [

    [0,1,2],
    [3,4,5],
    [
        ['a','b','c']
    ]

];
```